# Keep div entirely within viewport

Tags: javascript, html, css

As the title, I need to create an html tag and if the tag is hidden by the edge of the browser, it will automatically show back on the opposite side to no longer be hidden by the other. For example, it's like the options of facebook status:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RY7uy.png

Because I don't know how to explain it to everybody to understand, so I had captured a photo here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6I53z.png

This is html content:

```
<div class="status-options">
    <span class="status-options-list btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
    <ul class="u-1">
    <li><a href="#">Option 1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Can you post your code so we can see what you've got and can you explain what the issue is with what you have

Comment: I am not understanding the question completely, but taking a stab at it,  are you talking about something like overflow: visible css property?!!!

Comment: totally unclear what OP wants. "tag hidden by edge of browser" means what? Do you mean line breaks ?

Comment: @AxelAmthor I think he doesn't want that popup to go outside screen, he want's to move it completely above, where it can be seen in full.

Comment: I just add a photo to clarify my issue

Comment: @MihaiIorga: Yep, It's I mean. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: please provide the css for these classes `status-options status-options-list btn btn-default glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down`

Comment: @MihaiIorga got it: the topic then is/should be "Keep div entirely within viewport"